# How to return materials from a product or product levels

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a table that contains products and each product has other products that are used to manufacture. The products that are used to manufacture the parent product can be manufactured as well and contain other manufactured products. Example:

```
ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL   PRODUCTION   ID_MATERIAL
1                     2            2
1                     2            3
1                     2            4
2                     1            9
2                     1            10
3                     1            8
8                     1            5
```

Product 1 needs products 2,3 and 4, but product 2 and 3 are also manufactured. Product 2 needs 9 and 10 and 3 needs 8 and finally 8 needs 5. In this case we have levels here, product 1 is at level 1, products 2,3 and 4 are at level 2 and product 8 is at level 3. I tried to use a hierarchy of levels with recursion to make the select, but it turns out that it is not quite a hierarchy. SELECT used below returns me the following error:

```
SQL error: ORA-32044: Cycle detected when executing the recursive WITH query

WITH CTE (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL,PRODUCTION,ID_MATERIAL) AS (
  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL,
  PRODUCTION,
  ID_MATERIAL,
  FROM MATERIAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL,
  M.PRODUCTION,
  M.ID_MATERIAL,
  FROM MATERIAL M
  INNER JOIN CTE C
  ON M.ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL = C.ID_MATERIAL
  )
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

The columns ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL and ID_MATERIAL are derived from the products table. How to proceed in this case? Here is the structure of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(
  ID_PRODUCT NUMBER(6,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(200),
  WEIGHT NUMBER(6,2),
  PRICE NUMBER(6,2)
 );

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTION(
  ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION NUMBER(6,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  PRODUCTION NUMBER(3,0),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTIONPRODUCT FOREIGN KEY(ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID_PRODUCT)
 );

CREATE TABLE MATERIAL(
      ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL NUMBER(6,0),
      PRODUCTION NUMBER(3,0),
      ID_MATERIAL NUMBER(6,0), 
      CONSTRAINT PK_MATERIAL PRIMARY KEY(ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL, ID_MATERIAL),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT FOREIGN KEY (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID_PRODUCT),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTION FOREIGN KEY (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL) REFERENCES PRODUCTION(ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_MATERIAL) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID_PRODUCT)
     );

 INSERT INTO PRODUCT (ID_PRODUCT,NAME,WEIGHT,PRICE) VALUES (1,'PRODUCT A',10,5),
 (2,'PRODUCT B',10,5),
 (3,'PRODUCT C',10,5),
 (4,'PRODUCT D',10,5),
 (5,'PRODUCT E',10,5),
 (6,'PRODUCT F',10,5),
 (7,'PRODUCT G',10,5),
 (8,'PRODUCT H',10,5),
 (9,'PRODUCT I',10,5),
 (10,'PRODUCT J',10,5)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT (ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION,PRODUCTION) VALUES (1,2),
(2,1),
(3,1)

INSERT INTO MATERIAL (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL, PRODUCTION, ID_MATERIAL) VALUES (1,2,2),
(1,2,3),
(1,2,4),
(2,1,9),
(2,1,10),
(3,1,8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is OK, but somewhere in your real data appears a loop, for instance material 1 requires 3, 3 requires 8 and 8 requires 1. This way query would produce infinite rows, so Oracle reports cycle. This loop does not exists in sample data you provided.

There are several ways you can deal with cycles, but in this case I suspect you want to correct data. You can find problematic rows, for example use pseudocolumn `connect_by_is_cycle`:

```
select m.*, connect_by_iscycle
  from material m
  connect by nocycle prior id_material = id_product_material
```

In this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8e71384198b7b7fecc27faebf57541b) you can see the same error, cycle for material 8. I added one row to simulate this behavior.

You can also use RCTE with these clauses:

```
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order1
CYCLE id SET cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
```

as described in [documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2#cyclic)

Comment: I did as you suggested. But return to me as follows. Example: Product 1 depends on 2 and 3. It brings me the products that 1 needs, but it doesn't bring the products that 2 and 3 need.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but please try to revert connect by clause to: 'connect by nocycle  id_material = prior id_product_material'.

Comment: not yet. only bring me the products used in product 1.

Comment: Please look at provided [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2ac5291734e19e3d952634f20272cda). It works as expected, and I explained how cycle appears and how to find it. What else can I do?

Comment: In case I want to return only 1 level. Can you do with a subselect? How would it be?

Comment: Add `where` clause with desired number of levels, for example `where level <= 2` [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6107207b42e4cb65c240e51bd776c16f).